# Tree View or Heirarchical List in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want a tree like structured list in a app for WP8.
Is there a control item or toolkit item provided for the same, or would it require a creation of new style?

I basically want to display a list, in which all the list items can have further list structures as items.

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to use **TreeView** on WP8, the default style of hierarchical navigation on WP8 is by clicking items and using the back button to browse back .

If you still want to use **TreeView**, There is a TreeView control [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TreeView_WP8/) .